# How does Mathematica evaluate N[π, 30] == π?

Tags: machine-precision, number-representation, approximation, arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I want to know how `N[π, 30] == π` works. The result is `True`. I wonder whether the exact number  `π` is truncated to a `$MachinePrecision` number or `N[π, 30]` is extended to an exact number in a way similar to the output of this instruction `N[Pi, 30] // FullForm` (like stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482725/explanation-of-the-precision-and-the-accuracy-used-by-wolfram-mathematica-when-p)).

Comment: Look at the "Detail" of the docs for `Equal`: "Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)..." (of the precision of the expreassion, which is the lowest precision present, i.e. 30 digits in your example).

Comment: @MichaelE2 What is a bit puzzling is that `SetPrecision[N[Pi, 30], 55] == Pi` evaluates to `True` as well even though *naïvely* there appears to be a difference of not 7, but 25 digits.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Although `SetPrecision[N[Pi, 30], 55] - Pi` evaluates to somethign of the order $10^{-54}$. Freak accident?

Comment: @Szabolcs  All the digits in `N[Pi, 30] // FullForm` are correct, and there are more than 55 of them.  So it is equal to `Pi` to 55 digits. (The internal form of arbitrary precision carries extra guard digits. How many varies.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Indeed. Do you think it computes `Pi` to more than 30 digits (which is reasonable given that it may be hard to tell how many digits are *actually* correct), then artificially marks precision as "30 digits" even though it's storing many more?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, generally that's how `N[exact, prec]` works.  For `Pi`, there is an iterative algorithm ([there's a Q&A on that, sort of](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-digits-of-pi-using-mathematica)) in which each step adds many digits.  It might just keep all the digits known to be correct, once the result exceeds `prec` plus the minimum number of guards digits.  Or it might only keep an extra word or two to save memory.

Comment: @Szabolcs - look at `(N[Pi, #] // FullForm) & /@ Range[5, 75, 5]`

Comment: N[π,30] does not extend uniquely, so that's not a possibility. Such equality testing is performed at the smallest numeric precision of the input.