# What is the limit of digits to show in the conversion of an exact number to an Arbitrary Precision Number?

Tags: approximation, arbitrary-precision, rounding

By executing something like `N[π, c]` what is the maximum positive integer value `c` can have until the output is compromised by rounding errors?

Comment: As long as the original number is exact (e.g., `Pi`), the limit is probably determined by the memory available. The `Neat Examples` section of the documentation for `N` includes the example `Style[N[Pi, 10^5], 4]`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-digits-of-pi-using-mathematica